# Row counter in sub report - Jaspersoft

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a subreport that receives two parameters and therefore generates as many reports as there are combinations of parameters, I have to put a row counter in the sub report but this must not reset every report generated by the sub report but must continue the numbering.
This is a conversion from a crystal report
In crystal report do this:

shared numberVar J;

```
if trim({field})  <> '' then J:=J+1;
```

I have a subreport to which I pass in the sql query two parameters whose values ​​are generated by the main report, the combination of these parameters in the subreport generates a series of reports in the main report because the subreport is in the detail band.
In the subreport I have to insert a variable that counts the number of rows, but when I insert this variable the numeric counter is reset and starts counting in the new report generated by the subreport, I would like the counter not to reset

## Main report

- Detail of the band
- subreport

  ## Subreport
- report 1
  1 row
  2 rows
  3 rows
- report 2

1 row

2 rows

3 rows

I would like to have
- report 1

1 row

2 rows

3 rows

-report 2

4 rows

5 rows

6 rows

I hope I was clear
Do you have any ideas?
Can someone help me?
Please
Thanks a lot to everyone

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you need to accumulate number of rows at subreport and use it at subreport? You should post a couple of small *jrxml* files to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can pass back and forth a running row count variable to the subreport using parameters and return variables.

You'd need something like this:

(in the master report)

```
<!-- variable that stores the running row count in the master report -->
        <variable name="SubreportRowCount" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="System">
            <initialValueExpression>0</initialValueExpression>
        </variable>
...
                <subreport>
...
<!-- pass the current value to the subreport -->
                    <subreportParameter name="InitialRowCount">
                        <subreportParameterExpression>$V{SubreportRowCount}</subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
...
<!-- get back the updated value from the subreport -->
                    <returnValue subreportVariable="RunningRowCount" toVariable="SubreportRowCount"/>
    ...
                </subreport>
```

(in the subreport)

```
<!-- parameter that receives the initial value from the master -->
    <parameter name="InitialRowCount" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
...
<!-- running row count variable -->
    <variable name="RunningRowCount" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <variableExpression>$P{InitialRowCount} + $V{REPORT_COUNT}</variableExpression>
    </variable>
...
<!-- show the running count in a text element -->
            <textField>
...
                <textFieldExpression>$V{RunningRowCount}</textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
```